# pasting content in root should ask for password in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, root

I am aware the following actions can be done when I open nautilus as root, but is there a way to get nautilus to prompt for admin password when copying items(files, folders) into root folders from the default user account? Like a small script or something?
It is for usability, easier for novice users. :)

Comment: http://g-scripts.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Sreevisakh: doesnt help. I already use them. these scripts cannot paste into root file system folders